# How to send contents of visual selection to an external script

Tags: vimscript

I would like to write a python script that parses some vim data and returns a result. For example, we'll turn numbers, separated by lines, into a sorted list of unique numbers. If we had this as the input:

[image]

The python script would do:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.stdout.write('\n'.join([str(i) for i in (sorted(set([int(k) for k in sys.argv[-1].split()])))]))
```

This would expect the text from vim to be passed as an arg, so perhaps something like:

```
:imap <c-t> <c-r>=system('x.py <text_from_vim>')<cr>
```

And now vim would look like:

[image]

How could this be done?

Comment: Filter? `:%!` ...

Comment: @BLayer how would that work exactly?

Comment: What it does is take a range of lines and sends them as stdin to a command and the result replaces those lines. So, for example, `:%!sort` will sort the entire file (if you have a sort command in your shell) since `%` is short hand for "the whole file".

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for...you asked for content passed as args...but using stdin is more of a standard practice anyways. Can you adapt the script?

Comment: @BLayer sure that would work (if I can somehow fetch that value)...now just trying to find out how/if it's captured by the called python script.

Comment: It's all stdin/stdout ... certainly python has facilities for reading stdin.

Comment: @BLayer Would the actual call be: `:'<,'>!./x.py`, where `<...>` is the visually selected text?

Comment: That's right.. yep. (You don't  need to enter the range if you hit `:` from Visual mode. It's prepopulated.)

Comment: @BLayer nice, that is powerful!! I'm going to put up an answer just to show the full process.

Comment: Great opportunity to learn how to call external filters, but `:%sort | %!uniq` should do it, or `:%!sort | uniq` if you want to use external sort (I dont *think* vim has a builtin `:uniq` but I could be wrong).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble A couple hours ago I happened to be reading `:h list-modification` which includes an example that caught my eye (for no reason in particular, really). Fast forward to now, I see your comment, and somewhere a little bell starts to ring. The example? `:call uniq(sort(list))`. Oh, coincidences. You add such spice to life.  ;)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You can pass `u` to `:sort` to remove duplicates. For this example: `:4,11sort nu`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @BLayer for the suggestion here. Here is a [5s video of the result](https://imgur.com/vidgif/video?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgyazo.com%2F860f0d25246c1673b1333ce38ddaff58).

In summary, what was done is:

- The external (or internal) script will receive the lines as input to `stdin`. If sending the full file, you can use `:%!`, and if sending a visual selection, selecting the text and entering cmd mode will automatically do this, `'<,'>`.
- In the python (or any other extern script) you'd read stdin as text. In python, this is currently done by using `sys.stdin.read()`. So the full interaction looks like:

---

In vim:

```
 `:'<,'>!./x.py`
```

In python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
input_string = sys.stdin.read()
sys.stdout.write('\n'.join([str(i) for i in sorted(set([int(k) for k in input_string.split()]))]))
```

Additionally, you can pass command-line args by just entering them right into vim, for example:

```
:'<,'>!./x.py arg1 arg2
```